# Downloading problems

Tags: google-chrome

Everytime I try to download google chrome it tells me I can't because google chrome installation directory seems to be running and I should reboot and try again.So that's what I do and I get the same message.How can I fix this???

Comment: Try to delete `chrome.exe` from Task Manager, and then install Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Go to `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome`

   (or `C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome`)
2. Right click the application folder and select `Rename`.
3. Add `_old` at the end of the folder name .
4. Re-install Google Chrome.

This usually does the trick.